# Flutter/Riverpod - How update FutureProvider?

Tags: flutter, riverpod

I have FutureProvider in my app:

```
final myFutureProvider = FutureProvider<ProductLoadResult<Data>>((ref) async {
final connectivityResult = await (Connectivity().checkConnectivity());
final netAvailable = connectivityResult != ConnectivityResult.none;
if(netAvailable){
final productsApi = ref.read(productsApiProvider);
final result = await productsApi.getData();
  return ProductLoadResult<Data>(true, result);
}
else{
  return ProductLoadResult<Data>(false, null);
 }
});
```

therefore, in this provider, I check the network status and if the network is available, I receive data via the API.

using the provider:

```
final apiData =  ref.watch(myFutureProvider);
   body: apiData.when(
       data: _bodyForData,
       error: _bodyForError,
       loading: () => const Loader()),
```

if the network is not available, I display the button. on pressure the following logic:

```
 setState(() {
        //without this line, the value of categoriesFutureProvider is not updated
        ref.invalidate(categoriesFutureProvider);
  });
```

it works - but I'm not sure it's the optimal logic.

maybe there is a better option? I will be grateful for your help

Comment: firstly try to remove the setState from ref.invalidate its of no use there

Comment: To make your future provider cleaner you can move the logic to your repository/api class and only return ProductLoadResult in your future provider